# Bind html content in a loop using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to bind some html content in a loop using angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable">
<tr>
<td width="100" align="center">Time <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i><BR>Day <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i></td>
<td width="100" align="center" >9AM :: 10AM</td>
<td width="100" align="center">10AM :: 11AM</td>
<td width="100" align="center">11:15AM :: 12:15PM</td>
<td width="100" align="center">12:15PM :: 01:15PM</td>
<td width="100" align="center">02PM :: 03PM</td>
<td width="100" align="center">03PM :: 04PM</td>
<td width="100" align="center">04PM :: 05PM</td>
</tr>
<tbody id="detailsstockid">
<tr ng-repeat="days in noOfDays ">
<td width="100" align="center" style=" vertical-align:middle">{{days}}</td>
<td width="100" align="center" style="padding:0px;" >
<table style="margin:0px; padding:0px; width:100%">
<tr><td >
<select id="coy" name="coy" class="form-control" >
<option value="">Select Cource</option>
<option value="A">Theory1</option>
<option value="B">Theory2</option>
<option value="C">Theory3</option>
<option value="D">Theory4</option>      
</select>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<select id="coy" name="coy" class="form-control" >
<option value="">Select Faculty</option>
<option value="A">Faculty1</option>
<option value="B">Faculty2</option>
<option value="C">Faculty3</option>
<option value="D">Faculty4</option>         
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</td>
</table>
</td>
</tr>   
</tbody>
</table>
```

The following are my controller file code.

```
$scope.noOfDays=[];
    $scope.days={'0': "Monday", '1' : 'Tuesday' , '2' :'Wednesday' , '3' : 'Thursday' , '4': 'Friday'}
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
        $scope.noOfDays.push($scope.days[i]);
    }
```

In the above code i am able to bind days in a loop.I need here on each column of each row those select tag code will bind in a loop.Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Can you add what you have tried and why it didn't work?

Comment: What i have tried ,i already posted.Here days are coming in 1st column.From the 2nd column onwards those select values will add in each column.

Comment: @JasperZelf : No,each column is not updating.

Comment: @satya: sorry there, I didn't paste the link ;)
When I recreate your code in jsfiddle it works just fine. Are you sure you've added your controller using "ng-controller" or using the angular router? See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a snippet with a working code. I've moved the hours into a list ($scope.hours) and used ng-repeat to render them. So, you have a list of hours that you can use to populate every column of the row.

```js
var $scope = {};

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.controller('tableCtrl', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {

        $scope.noOfDays = [];
        
        $scope.gridData = {};

        $scope.days = {
          '0': "Monday",
          '1': 'Tuesday',
          '2': 'Wednesday',
          '3': 'Thursday',
          '4': 'Friday'
        }
        
        $scope.hours = [
          '9AM :: 10AM',
          '10AM :: 11AM',
          '11:15AM :: 12:15PM',
          '12:15PM :: 01:15PM',
          '02PM :: 03PM',
          '03PM :: 04PM',
          '04PM :: 05PM'
        ]

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          $scope.noOfDays.push($scope.days[i]);
        }

      }]);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="tableCtrl">
  
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable">
  <tr>
    <td width="100" align="center">Time <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>
      <br>Day <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i>
    </td>
    <td width="100" align="center" ng-repeat="hour in hours" ng-bind="hour"></td>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="detailsstockid">
    <tr ng-repeat="day in noOfDays">
      <td width="100" align="center" style=" vertical-align:middle" ng-bind="day"></td>
      <td width="100" align="center" style="padding:0px;" ng-repeat="hour in hours">
        <table style="margin:0px; padding:0px; width:100%">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <select id="coy" name="coy" class="form-control" ng-model="gridData[day][hour].course">
                <option value="">Select Cource</option>
                <option value="A">Theory1</option>
                <option value="B">Theory2</option>
                <option value="C">Theory3</option>
                <option value="D">Theory4</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <select id="coy" name="coy" class="form-control" ng-model="gridData[day][hour].faculty">
                <option value="">Select Faculty</option>
                <option value="A">Faculty1</option>
                <option value="B">Faculty2</option>
                <option value="C">Faculty3</option>
                <option value="D">Faculty4</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  
  {{gridData}}
</div>
```

Comment: i need to display those select tag codes in each column.

Comment: @satya is it what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: In your way i am getting all days in one column and select course/select faculty in another column.But here i need the select course/faculty in each column rather than days column with respect to those time.

Comment: @ vinagreti : Here when i am tring to get selected course and faculty value by using $scope.course and $scope.faculty ,its showing null.Can you please resolve this.

Comment: @satya I've edited the answer to do what you want. Look at the scope variable `$scope.gridData = {};`

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted works fine: The code you posted works fine when I copied it in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jkrielaars/ejx7tmud/1/

Maybe you forgot to invoke the right controller in your html?

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
```

Or in your routing:

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })
```

**UPDATE**

replaced the jsfiddle URL...

Answer (score -1):

updated: your json is not valid! check in jsonlint

`<tr ng-repeat="days in noOfDays ">
<td width="100" align="center" style=" vertical-align:middle">{{days}}</td>`

> if you have data in your noOfDays scope you will have access to that in view as i mentioned below!

Comment: @ mohsen : how it will bind those values.